# How to manage Invalid Input path Exception - MLCP?

Tags: linux, marklogic, marklogic-8, mlcp

I am trying to load some csv files located in windows, into Marklogic DB using mlcp command as follows:

```
./mlcp.sh import -mode local -options_file ../conf/conn.txt -input_file_path "/windows_path/" -input_file_type delimited_text -generate_uri -output_uri-replace "/windows_path/,'/file_path/'"
```

Got the following exception:

```
INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Content type: XML
ERROR contentpump.ContentPump:Error running a ContentPump job
java.io.IOException: No input files found with the specified input path file:/windows_path/ and input file pattern .* 
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file: /windows_path/
```

But files are available in the windows path. when I try to execute the following command from Linux server

```
cd /windows-path/
```

I get the following exception:

```
-bash: cd: /windows_path/: Key has expired
```

I am new to Linux, could anyone explain. Why such exception? Do I need to mount the windows path in Linux server? If so, how can I acheive it?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - are you trying to load the documents from Windows via Linux? Why are you executing 'cd /windows-path' from Linux?

Comment: i am trying to execute 'cd /windows-path/'  just to verify whether the files are available or it can be open from linux path.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/63277/mount-cifs-share-gives-mount-error-127-key-has-expired  Looks like it could be a password issue?

Comment: try to add the path without quotes: -input_file_path path/to/data

Comment: Are you running mlcp on Windows, in order to load the contents of /windows_path/ into MarkLogic running on Linux? If so, /windows_path/ doesn't need to be accessible from your MarkLogic host. The files are read in on the client side (Windows). Just run mlcp from your Windows host. On the other hand, if you have the files on Windows and want to run mlcp from some Linux host, then, yes, that filesystem has to be mounted on the Linux host, and the path would be the path under which it is mounted, rather than the path you'd use on Windows.

Comment: I have now mounted the windows path in Linux server. But when i tried to open the path, just to view the files i get error message as 'key has expired'. I have already changed the password for Linux server. SO what does this mean?